# caffe without root: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxxxx

Tags: compiler-errors, caffe

I try to install caffe without root on a linux system. I found this [this](http://autchen.github.io/guides/2015/04/03/caffe-install.html) instruction for doing so. Now at some point when I compile caffe I get this error message:

```
$make all -j8
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglog
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5_hl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lhdf5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsnappy
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:563: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3' failed
```

Does somebody know how to fix this without root privileges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistakes:

1. hdf5_hl, hdf5 and glog by default compile into a "lib64" instead a "lib" folder
2. snappy I simply set the wrong path at "--prefix="
3. In my Makefile.config I needed to set "BLAS := open" instead of "BLAS := atlas"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `caffe` dependencies, before doing `make all -j8`.

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt-get install -y libprotobuf-dev libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libhdf5-serial-dev protobuf-compiler
 sudo apt-get install -y libatlas-base-dev 
 sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libboost-all-dev
 sudo apt-get install -y libgflags-dev libgoogle-glog-dev liblmdb-dev
```

Comment: As mentioned above I don't have root privileges